# Problem with Boolean Difference Overhang

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I continue to be challenged with boolean difference. This time I have used the 3D Print add-on. It is telling me that there is an Overhang Face. In edit mode I select "Overhang Face: 1". It shows me the face and I don't understand why it is overhanging.

[image]

Note that I have already attempted to clean things up "Remove By Distance" and have done other cleanup.

[Here is file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/177zFCGMHrqfn5_eHvupSuKVvCBeL80mi)

Comment: Thanks. This is not an easy problem to visualize but will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand it can take awhile to wrap your head around it.  I create all my 3D printed models using **Blender 2.91**.  The Boolean operator has been greatly improved using the **exact and self options** (Although the **Fast** option will work with this model just as well)

[image: Exact Self]

**1st)** The overhang is just the bottom face. Should print just fine not sure if your printer will require supports for the hole though.
[image: Overhang]

**2nd)** Animation of doing Boolean - Difference with your object.
[image: Boolean]

**3rd)** Animation of overhang location and how to find it.
[image: Overhang]

**4th)** If you want to display the hole during edit mode you have to enable it or apply the modifier)
[image: Hole enabled]

**5th)** Exported to slicer note: not sure if your printer will require supports for the hole or not.
[image: Slicer]

Comment: Wow, thank you for the super detailed answer to my question. This is awesome!  I will see if I can successfully recreate what you have done:)

Comment: @Dale anytime the users in this group have helped me a lot so I try and pass it along when I can.  And if you decide to do more CAD like things using Blender this channel will help out `A LOT`.  https://www.youtube.com/c/MakerTales/videos

Comment: Hi Rick, I was initially stuck when following your steps. The export had the calendar included. After a bit of web research, I went back and clicked "Selection Only" during the export. This worked! Is this the right way to go about it?  And thanks for the pointer to the videos.

Comment: @Dale the only right way is what works best for your work flow.  For me, I just select the object I want to export as an STL and use the 3D-print tab.  https://i.imgur.com/cVKMoEu.png